# Print different sizes pages in Java with Java Print Services

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print different sized pages in JPS using a Book object. I create a custom PageFormat and I have a custom print() method in the SwingComponent. I can see that the PageFormat is correct, but the actual printed page always takes the size of the first page, not the page size for each PageFormat.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can give the PrinterJob a

> HashPrintRequestAttributeSet

where you can set the Preferences (for PrintDialog), but i see no sense to use it for every page, try to adjust in the print() method, for every page, the mentioned Set.